# Shaking/moving/trembling background-image in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mozilla

I have a problem with background image on my website in Mozilla and I am depressed because I do not know how to solve it ... The problem is kindly strange, please look :

[MY WEBSITE](http://www.rask.pl/test/jopillo/dziesiec-filmow-ktorych-nie-moz-65.html) (please look in Mozilla)

Background of main photo is shaking/moving/trembling... After click on thumb below - it's stabilized.

Backgrounds of images are taking from 'onclick' but I don't think it's important. Of course:

```
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
```

Any clue? I would be glad for any kind of help... :)

Comment: Your page has both JavaScript and HTML errors. You should fix those first.

Comment: I used Firefox, reloaded it 5 times, and couldn't see any shaking.

Comment: Works fine for Internet Explorer :)  (Could it be your background-position:center center; property?  Try removing that to see if the background fixes itself)

Comment: I know HTML errors but JS errors?? Can you tell me how did you check it?

Comment: Right click on the page, go to "inspect element" and then click on console. You should see your JS errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the image url for #mainphoto

on load of the page the image url is in single quotes

```
background-image:url('upload/Images/Uzytkownicy/test/119e0b1f9e3eaf8ef1e07c850d228310.jpg');
```

and on click it changes to double quotes

```
background-image: url("upload/Images/Uzytkownicy/test/119e0b1f9e3eaf8ef1e07c850d228310.jpg");
```

when i edited it from browser inspect element i was able to see the issue

Comment: Thank you Vitorino! That was it! :)